# I need to find string values in a column and then join it to the next table with the generated string value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a case when the string value is stored in a statement as a column value in a table, and I need to join that string value with another table where string value which helps to identify which rows to be included.

### Table 1

```
ID     Name          Value 
1       Jack         I work in Amazon and I like to read. 
2       Mary         I work in Facebook and prefer to play Basketball. 
3       Klay         I play football and work at Google. 
4       Josh         I work for UN and I like travelling. 
5       Jane         I am currently a student and I play Hockey.
```

### Table 2

```
    Value          Include
   Basketball         Y 
   Hockey             Y 
   Football           Y 
    Read              N
   Travelling         N
```

So from Table 1 I need to find the string values and then join it to this table to determine if it is 'Y' value or 'N' value. Is there any way to just separate those values from Table 1.

### Expected Result when Table 1 Joined to Table 2

```
ID     Name          Include
1       Jack         N
2       Mary         Y 
3       Klay         Y
4       Josh         N
5       Jane         Y
```

Comment: Please share your expected result and explain it

Answer (score 0):

Not going to be all that efficient, but it can't be helped the way the tables are laid out. Just join on a LIKE operator.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1
JOIN   Table2 
ON     Table1.Value LIKE '%' + Table2.Value '%'
WHERE  Table2.Include = 'Y'
```